# Display drupal 7 site in iframe?

Tags: social-network

I have a Drupal 7 site and a Facebook page. I have created a tab on the Facebook page which should allow me to display a page from my Drupal site within the tab. On Microsoft Edge I get a warning saying that the site doesn't allow iframes, on all other browsers I have tried nothing displays at all.

I have enabled Security Kit, disabled X-XSS-Protection, allowed cross-site request  from https://facebook.com and disabled X-Frame-Options.

I enabled the iFrame entity module and allowed nodes to be iFramed.

And I have put `$conf['x_frame_options'] = '';` in my settings.php.

I still am unable to display a node from my site on an iframe.

How do I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211981/how-to-enable-drupal-site-to-be-in-an-iframe but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I put this towards the end of settings.php (Drupal 7). It worked for me:

```
$conf['x_frame_options'] = 'ALLOW-FROM .facebook.com';
```

(I also use SSL/https (Let's Encrypt) on this site.)

`x_frame_options` don't allow for multiple values, i think. So `'allow-from domain.com'` might disallow SAMEORIGIN. From [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2820340#comment-11861305) it looks like the module [Security Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit) allow for setting Allow-From dynamically based on the current page request. I haven't tested it myself.